# Double click readonly field does not get focused immediately, but an external button runs same code does

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have the below template in my input component as part of the bigger component.
For some reason when I click the pencil button that makes the field focused shows the cursor inside the input. But the same function that runs when I dblClick the field does not get the cursor ready in the field. So it is not immediately focused when double clicked. Actually I would like it to select it all too if there is value.

How can I make sure they work similar?

```
<div class="row detail-row " [ngClass]="{'invalid': (invalid),  'valid': 
(!invalid), 'focused': (onFocused)}" parentControl>
        <div class="col col-sm-4">
            <label class="labelheading">{{ labelKey| translate}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-8">
            <input [attr.id]="fieldId"
                   type="text"
                   [readonly]="readField"
                   (blur)="onBlurEvent(elem)"
                   (dblclick)="onDoubleClick(elem)"
                   class="form-control"
                   [(ngModel)]="fieldValue"
                   #elem
                   [attr.name]="fieldId"
                   (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
        </div>
        <span *ngIf="!readOnly">
            <button class="btn-link edit-icon"
                    (click)="onBtnPencilClick(elem)"
                    title="Edit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" alt="Edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="!hideSaveButtons">
        <remove-add-buttons [showBtn]="showButtons"
                        (onBtnAdd)="onButtonSave()"
                        (onBtnRemove)="ontButtonCancel()">
        </remove-add-buttons>
        </span>
        <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="error-message" > {{errorMessage}}</div>
    </div>
```

And these are the functions that button and dblClick runs.

```
onDoubleClick = (e: any): void => {
    this.setInputValuesAndSetFocus(e);
}
onBtnPencilClick = (e: any): void => {
   this.setInputValuesAndSetFocus(e);
}

private setInputValuesAndSetFocus = (e: any): void => {
    this.showButtons = true;
    this.readField = false;
    this.onFocused = true;
    e.focus();

}
```

Comment: It just so happened that a button is focused on click, your e.focus() is not doing anything, I think you should call `e.target.focus()`

Comment: calling e.target.focus() actually resulted the pencil button stop working  and the double click issue did not change.

Comment: I'm not sure if it affects but could you change the parameter in the template from elem to $events? `onBtnPencilClick($event)` Also, consider logging the event object to see what you get

Comment: I have seen selecting the existing value function e.select(); and adding that to the function seems to be working now I can see cursor coming up after dblclick instead of another click needed. Is this an acceptable solution?

Comment: This is what I get for e element in the console.
e: input.form-control.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about selecting e.select(). You should get a MouseEvent from (click) and (dblclick)

Comment: Please check my question. My question is not about mouse event but the (text) cursor not being in ready state for focused input. e.select(); selects the elements value which can be empty, but makes the cursor ready inside the input field.

Comment: HTMLInputElement.select() will work, but note that it works only for <textarea> or <input>